# React includes \n in Json returned from Flask API

Tags: reactjs, json, api, flask

I´ve defined an end point in my FLASK API app as follows:

```
@app.route("/get_data", methods=["GET"])
def get_data():
    collection = mongo.db["colection_name"]
    query_results = collection.find_one()
    return jsonify(list(query_results))
```

It returns the data from MongoDB in JSON format and I can perfectly fetch it in Python using the **requests** library, which look as follows:

```
[
  {
    "date": "Sat, 01 Jan 1983 00:00:00 GMT",
    "tmed": 5.9
  },
  {
    "date": "Sun, 02 Jan 1983 00:00:00 GMT",
    "tmed": 4.4
  }, ...
]
```

However, when I call it from my React app using the following format

```
const getData = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await axios.get(
          `http://127.0.0.1:5000/get_data`
        );
        setData(res.data);}
```

It returns it in an unformatted string manner, where `\n` are added. That makes React to not consider the data as an array and subsequently to not display it correctly. That is the format in which React receives the data:

```
'[\n  {\n    "date": "Sat, 01 Jan 1983 00:00:00 GMT" \n "tmed ..... }\n]\n'
```

I am not sure if the issue is in the Flask or in the React side. Any way to make Flask correctly return the data or React to consume it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underlying problem was some `NaN` values generated in my Python component and included in the JSON. JavaScript doesn´t deal with `NaN` but `Null` values and does not understand the first. That turned the returned object into a large string rather than a real JSON.

Once I replaced the `NaN` values in my Python module with `None` values, JavaScript correctly turned them into `Null`, and the JSON was imported correctly.